# Is there a closed form expression for this sum?

Tags: summation, closed-form

I'm wondering whether this sum has a closed form expression:

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\sum^{r_0+k}_{r=r_0}\frac{{(p - r)}^{0.75}}{r^2}$$

I can do this: Let $z = p - r$ then $r = p - z$

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\sum^{p - r_0 - k}_{z=p - r_0}\frac{{z}^{0.75}}{(p - z)^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\sum^{p - r_0 - k}_{z=p - r_0}\frac{{z}^{0.75}}{p^2 - 2zp + z^2}$$

But then it's unclear where to go from here. Any ideas? I have no idea if there even is a solution for this. This does not look like the series I have studied in calculus. Does this form of summation have a name? Is it known to have a closed form?

Comment: I doubt there is a useful closed form. There *might* be some special functions that can be used.